# ASP.NET MVC 4 File Upload With Trigger || Html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I have a working code of upload multiple files that i'm pretty much satisfied from it, but i want to add an "upload trigger" so i can upload files from different directory, how can i do it ?

I'm using MVC 4, and this is my code: (regarding to the files upload)

**Index:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
           {
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>File:</td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="Files" id="Files" multiple /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>   
           }
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index(Scan scan)
        {
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
    savefile....
    ......
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

I want to be able to choose files multiply times and add them to a list that the user can see the files he chosen till now, and when the user is ready he press the trigger button "upload", all the files will send in a HTTP POST to the controller same as before, does it possible?

I'm new in web programming so js, jquery, ajax, are not my strong side :)

p.s i tried to use a bunch of stuff to implement what i want :
"fine-uploader", "Uploadify", "jQuery File Upload" 
and i didn't achieved nothing, its very complicated with my lack of knowledge

Comment: What you're wanting to achieve is only possible through *something* dynamic on the client-side like JS (in modern browsers), Flash, or Java (though for the love of everything good and holy, don't use Java). If you have a "lack of knowledge" that is preventing you from utilizing those methods, unfortunately, there's no magic wand we can wave for you. You're just going to have to dig into the docs, read some books or tutorials, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the AJAX toolkit for the Multiple File Uploads.
It should be relatively easy to implement and they have instructions for you to install it.

The control allows you to upload multiple files that are stored in the temp directory of the server. When the form is finally submitted, you have the control to upload the files.

Here are steps to implement the AJAX tool kit:

1) Use NuGet and add the Ajax toolkit controls to your project; if you don't have nuget, download it and add it to your project by going to this link here:  ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/

2) Once you have it in your project, implement by doing the following lines in your page

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,png,gif" MaximumNumberOfFiles="10" OnUploadComplete="File_Upload" Width="500px" />
```

3) In the code behind, handle the files here

> ```
> protected void File_Upload(object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
> {
>     string filename = e.FileName;
>     string strDestPath = Server.MapPath("~/Documents/");
>     AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(@strDestPath + filename);       
> }
> ```

Once you get there, you can handle your file uploads.

A good demo of it can be found here: 
http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/ajax-fileupload-or-multiple-fileupload-with-progress-example-in-Asp-Net-1081.aspx